# awscli default configuration credentials on ec2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have an ec2 instance with a specific role,
when typing the awscli command:

```
[TEST@JenkinsSlave ~]$ aws configure list
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************E25I         iam-role
secret_key     ****************Yl4d         iam-role
    region                <not set>             None    None
```

I can see that I have an access key and secret key which I didn't create,
This is a clean amazon Linux ami with no configuration.

I thought it was the role keys but there is no such thing as assigning keys to a role, and every time I create a new server I get different keys so it looks like random keys.
does anyone know how I got those credentials?

and How I can delete them from my configuration (as you can see by **Location=None** they are not stored in **~/.aws/**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you don't have an instance role assigned, your EC2 instance does have instance-based credentials. You can see these with `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/identity-credentials/ec2/security-credentials/ec2-instance`.

However, when I run `aws configure list`, those credentials don't show up. It's possible that you're running an earlier or later version than I am (aws-cli/1.16.153) and the behavior has changed. You can compare the credentials from that `curl` request to see if they're the same.

You should verify that you don't, in fact, have an instance role set. Either check the console or use `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/` from the instance. If you *don't* have a role set you'll get a 404. If you do have a role set this command will show a file named `info`, and that file will contain the instance role information.

---

Edit: the only thing that I've tried that *does* produce the output you're seeing is to assign an instance profile to the instance.

---

In response to comment asking about different tokens for each machine: this is how instance profiles work. Each machine gets a time-limited set of credentials that can be used to make requests, and automatically renews those credentials as needed. This is a Good Thing, as it means that those credentials can not be taken from the machine and used to gain unauthorized access to the services.

Comment: What is that IP address that you mare using?

Comment: @ShacharHamuzimRajuan - that's the instance metadata address. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: But if I assigned an instance profile how come I get different keys for every instance which I deploy the same way?